# Use LESS file in WordPress that compiles on the fly

Tags: css, wordpress, frontend, wordpress-theming, less

I am developing a WordPress Plugin. Which have the dynamic colors options from WordPress Backend.

Now, in a plugin, I am using the LESS file with variables to give the dynamic output to the users whenever they change the colors from Backend Admin Settings.

If anyone can help me with the tool that compiles the LESS file on the fly and make the CSS file.
OR
Can I use the LESS file directly in my WordPress `enqueue_script`?

Please suggest the best.

Comment: For dynamic styles it is usually better to just inline them as CSS. Easier to do and works faster.

Comment: @PaulMitchell there are other things as well inline with Colors. Colors are just one of them. Otherwise, the question would be longer than it should be if I have mentioned them all. Can you give me an idea of how I can use LESS in WordPress?

Comment: The only place where I saw something similar done right is https://generatepress.com/. This theme creates  external files out of user-settings and enqueues them alongside default styles. I think that they use SCSS there but general implementation is the same, you can check out their code, it's free https://wordpress.org/themes/generatepress/